# Nuxt js dynamic route not work after generate

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3

in my project i am using nuxt js. I have a route looks like
**service/:slug**
After build and generate my all route works perfectly.Bellow code I use to generate dynamic route on generate

```js
  generate: {

    routes(callback) {
      axios
        .get('url')
        .then(res => {
          const routes = res.data.data.map(service => {
            return '/services/' + service.slug
          })
          callback(null, routes)
        })
        .catch(callback)
      axios
        .get('https://url')
        .then(res => {
          const routes = res.data.data.map(offer => {
            return '/campaigns/' + offer.slug
          })
          callback(null, routes)
        })
        .catch(callback)
    }
  }
```

But problem occurs when I create another new item from admin panel after build and generate.

seems I have three route when I run **nuxt generate**

1. service/cash
2. service/profit

now after host my dist folder in server then I hit **www.url/service/cash** and its work perfectly.

Now I create a new service item in admin panel called **send-money**
Then when I hit on browser using **www.url/service/send-money**
Its not working and get 404.

now I cant understand how can I solve this situation.

Answer (score 1):

When using `SSG` nuxt only generates the available pages in your project. This is how `SSG` works. Therefore, you need to create a custom `script` in your server to run ‍`yarn build && yarn generate` command after creating new page.

For example, let us assume you are creating a blog. When you use ‍‍‍`yarn generate`, nuxt generates the posts fetched from the database at that specific time and moves them inside `dist` folder. Therefore, you need to attach a custom script -which you need to somehow create in the backend- to run `yarn build && yarn generate` after creation of a new post.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using something like firebase static hosting...you only need to make sure you have wildcard rewrites rules in place to prevent 404 errors. In this case this is what I have in my firebase.json files.

```json
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```